# Delete part of a bake

Tags: animation, physics, baking, cloth-simulation, cache

I have some cloth simulation on a character. It works well until some clipping happens at Frame 30. Is it possible to delete the bake after Frame 30, but keep Frame 1~29 untouched, therefore I can adjust the character at Frame 30 and run simulation from there?

[image]